# git log "--function-context"

Tags: git, logging, diff

I want to generate unified diff with the full function/method context.
In ubuntu, when I am using the command: "git log --no-merges -p --function-context", 
I am getting the following error:

"fatal: unrecognized argument: --function-context".

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --no-merges -p --function-context` works just fine with my git 1.8.5 (msysgit on Windows).
This isn't surprising considering that the [`git log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) does mention:

> The command takes options applicable to the `git rev-list` command to control what is shown and how, and options applicable to the `git diff-*` commands to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.

Check the version of your Git: it is possible it doesn't support that argument yet.

---

That `--function-context` was introduced with [commit 14937c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14937c2c06e63f93f65e1bc6693b95d4e54053d7), by René Scharfe, for git 1.7.8 (December 2011).

> Add the option `-W/--function-context` to git diff.
>   It is similar to the same option of [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) and expands the context of change hunks
>   so that the whole surrounding function is shown.
>   This "natural" context can allow changes to be understood better.